# Facebook Sign-In Web Integration - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, django-rest-framework, facebook-login

I'm trying to integrate the Facebook sign-in into my HTML.
I managed to get it working once previously:

```
Click on Login button -> popup -> Login with Facebook -> Log in Button changed to 'Logout'.
Click on Logout button - > button changes to 'Login'.
```

but I eventually have been failing to do so again.

I'm testing on both my local server as well as a deployment to a Google Cloud Server.

On my local, clicking on the button at least gets me a Facebook page(mentioning something about not using a secured connection).

Once deployed to the Cloud, I keep getting a `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch` which I dont understand what it means.

I am also not sure if it matters, but after the above error, this then displays
`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` sourced to the Facebook AJAX.

The relevant HTML page:

```
{% block content %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" media="all" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<head>

    <title>Google Signin Testing</title>
    <style>
    .left {
        float: left;
        width: 40%;
        padding-left:32%;
        padding-top:13%;
        height: 75%
        }
    .right {
        float: left;
        width: 40%;
        padding-top:5%;
        height: 100%
        }

    h1 {
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #aaa;
        }

    h2.maintitle {
        padding-left:5%;
        font-variant: small-caps;
        font-size: 36px;'
        }

    </style>

    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>

    <script>
    function onSignIn(credentialResponse) {
        document.body.innerHTML = "Signed in";
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                    appId      : '[app-id]',  // Based on the App ID in Facebook Developer Account
                    cookie     : true, // Enable cookies to allow the server to access the session.
                    xfbml      : true, // Parse social plugins on this webpage.
                    version    : 'v11.0'  // Use this Graph API version for this call.
                });
            FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
        };

        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        function checkLoginState() { // Called when a person is finished with the Login Button.
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) { // See the onlogin handler
                console.log(response);
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });
        }

    </script>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <!-- Load the JS SDK asynchronously -->
    <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v11.0&appId=[appid]&autoLogAppEvents=1" nonce="Q0pn37OG"></script>
    


    <div class='row' >
        <div class='container-fluid col-6 left' >
        </div>

        <div class='container-fluid col-6 right' >  

            <h1>{% trans 'Log-In' %}</h1>
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                <p>{% trans 'You are already logged in' %}, <a href="{% url 'login_success' %}">my homepage</a></p>
            {% else %}
                <form action="" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
                        {% for x in form.non_field_errors %}
                            <text style="color:red; font-size:12px;" id='{{field.label}}'><b>{{x}}</b></text>
                            <p/>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}

                    {% for field in form %}
                        <div class="fieldWrapper">
                            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
                            <br/>
                            {% for x in field.errors %}
                                <text style="color:red; font-size:12px;" id='{{field.label}}'><b>{{x}}</b></text>
                            {% endfor %}
                            <p/>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}

                    <input style='max-height:8vh;font-size:clamp(5px, 2.3vh, 30px);object-fit;' type="submit" value="Log In"></input>
                    <br/><br/>

                    <div id="g_id_onload"
                         data-client_id="[Google Cloud ID]"
                         data-context="signin"
                         data-ux_mode="redirect"
                         data-login_uri="[Google Cloud URL]"
                         data-auto_prompt="false">
                    </div>

                    <div class="g_id_signin"
                         data-type="standard"
                         data-shape="rectangular"
                         data-theme="filled_blue"
                         data-text="signin_with"
                         data-size="medium"
                         data-logo_alignment="left"
                         data-width=300 >
                    </div>
                </form>

                <br/><br/><p><a href="">{% trans 'Forgotten your password?' %}</a></p>

            {% endif %} 

        </div>

    </div>

</body>


<!--Redirection if already Logged-In in cookies -->
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
<script type="text/javascript">
var csrftoken  = Cookies.get('csrftoken'); //using js.cookie.js

window.location = "{% url 'login_success' %}";

</script>
{% endif %}
</html> 

{% endblock %}
```

The HTML code more or less has not changed from when I first tried it.
I'm also attempting to integrate Google Sign-In into the page, hence why it looks like so

My backend is using Python Django.

Within the Facebook for Developer site, I have included the provided URL when I deployed to the Cloud as part of the `Allowed Domains for the JavaScript SDK` field.

App.yaml details:

```
# [START runtime]
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT Login.wsgi --preload --timeout 120
beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: [GCloud Instance]

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

handlers:
  - url: /favicon\.ico
    static_files: favicon.ico
    upload: favicon\.ico

  - url: /static
    static_dir: /static

  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    script: auto

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 1
  max_concurrent_requests: 80

# [END runtime]
```

*Edit*

Seems that I missed out the actual Facebook integration code in my sample html. My bad. Error still persist though.

Also, I dont know why, but I went to the Facebook Developer page, create a new app, enabled the Javascript SDK, inserted my deployed url into `Allowed Domains for the JavaScript SDK` field, used the App ID of this new app and inserted it into the relevant fields, redeployed the code to the cloud, reset .....and its working again all of a sudden. What happened?

*Edit 2*

It seems I spoke too soon.
I managed to get the login page to popup, but when attempting to actually log in, I get the error again.

Comment: You have stated that you are deploying the `html` page to Google Cloud Server. Can you please add more details like which infrastructure in Google Cloud Platform (Google App Engine/ Google Kubernetes Engine/ Google Compute Engine or anything else) you are using to deploy the `html` page and any specific documentation you are following?

Comment: @Prabir I've edited the op to include my ```app.yaml``` details. Documentation would be the one provided by [Facebook themselves](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web). Im not doing anything special: just trying to integrate the Facebook login into my code

Answer (score -1):

I am also integrating FB Login (js sdk) into a webapp (php in my case) and get that error as well - all of my testing is only localhost(ssl on) - haven't had the chance to test on a "live" server.

I am too much of a novice (or maybe FB docs are pretty bad - or a bit of both) to understand the error (I can get to the point of getting the user node I need - I only get FBuserid, name, locale, email, and profile picture URL - all of which are retrieved and logged into console for debugging purposes), and I also get a failed to load resource error that seems to be related to images(fb pixel something?).

[console_log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewPAV.png)

I'm watching this topic closely cause maybe, just maybe I'll be able to answer my questions. In the event I stumble upon a solution, I'll paste it here (just don't ask me to explain it in detail! :D ).

------------------------------------------------------------

edit: I am pretty sure the error is still being displayed and doesn't actually impact one's ability to query the API. I solved the problems with my integration (a silly mistake in a SQL query was all that was holding me back), since I could retrieve the user node and info I need for my case.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).