# Facebook JavaScript SDK - Login not working in Brave browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, brave

I am trying to implement Facebook JS SDK in my React application (created using `create-react-app`) but unfortunately the login is not working in [Brave browser](https://brave.com). The login window opens up fine however I am getting the following error in the application:

```
Failed to fetch
TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at https://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29875:111
    at i (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=9ce9d98548b3f81266135fe023af13ec:111:957)
    at h (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=9ce9d98548b3f81266135fe023af13ec:111:795)
    at Object.a [as log] (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=9ce9d98548b3f81266135fe023af13ec:111:1675)
    at Object.i [as logEvent] (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=9ce9d98548b3f81266135fe023af13ec:126:739)
    at k (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=9ce9d98548b3f81266135fe023af13ec:155:2817)
    at transform (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=9ce9d98548b3f81266135fe023af13ec:155:4056)
    at Object.prepareCall (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=9ce9d98548b3f81266135fe023af13ec:155:7687)
    at a (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=9ce9d98548b3f81266135fe023af13ec:156:1075)
    at Object.a [as login] (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=9ce9d98548b3f81266135fe023af13ec:127:618)
```

Interesting thing is that if I try to run the same code in other browsers (I tried Safari and Microsoft Edge), I don't get any errors.

I found a similar question here: [Facebook Sign-In Web Integration - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69023856/facebook-sign-in-web-integration-uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-failed-to-fe) however it did not resolve the issue I am facing.

It seems there's one particular script (`https://www.facebook.com/platform/impression.php/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/?api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&lid=117&payload=%7B%22payload%22%3A%7B%22cbt_delta%22%3A0%2C%22logger_id%22%3A%22xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%22%2C%22action%22%3A%22client_login_start%22%2C%22client_funnel_version%22%3A1%7D%2C%22source%22%3A%22jssdk%22%7D`) which is being blocked by Brave as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

I am wondering why I am getting the error only in Brave browser and is there a setting there which would prevent this error from happening. Furthermore, is it ok to swallow the error by putting the login call in try/catch block?

Here's the code to initialize the Facebook SDK:

```
window.FB.init({
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
  cookie: true,
  xfbml: true,
  version: 'v17.0',
});
```

And this is how I am calling the login method:

```
export async function login() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    window.FB.login(
      function (response: any) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
          console.info(response.authResponse);
        } else {
          console.error('User canceled login or did not authorize');
        }
      },
      {
        // scope: '',
        return_scopes: true,
        enable_profile_selector: true,
        config_id: process.env.REACT_APP_FACEBOOK_CONFIG_ID,
      },
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the "Finished" Column, it starts with "block". Be aware that the Facebook SDK tries to load an external script, which gets blocked by the Brave Browser: https://brave.com/shields/

More information: https://brave.com/learn/turn-off-ad-blockers/

> Ads and trackers, fingerprinting, cookies, and more are all blocked by default.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also suspected the same. What's the solution in this case? Asking users to turn off ad blockers is certainly not an option.

Comment: unfortunately, i do not think there is any solution for this. brave browser is meant for maximum data privacy, but the market share is quite small, i guess.